# Printing an object value in gdb

Tags: c++, gdb

This seems to be a trivial question, but I could not find an answer to it.

Suppose that I have defined a class `Widget` and created the overload:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const Widget &w) {...}
```

Is there a way to examine a `Widget` object in `gdb` by simply printing it using the above overload?

I am using gdb version 7.7.1.

**EDIT**:

Suppose that `w` is a `Widget` object. I am trying this:

```
call operator<<(std::cout, w)
```

and getting the following error message from gdb:

```
(std::ostream &) @0x615120: <incomplete type>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (gdb 7.9.1):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    int i = 17;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Foo &foo)
{
    os << "i: " << foo.i << "\n";
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    f.i = 40;

    std::cout << f;
}
```

I compiled it like this (gcc 5.2):

> g++ -Wall -ggdb -std=c++11 test.cpp

and run under gdb

> (gdb) br main Breakpoint 1 at 0x400858: file test.cpp, line 14. (gdb)
>   r Starting program:
>   /home/evgeniy/projects/study_c++/operator_print_gdb/a.out
>
> Breakpoint 1, main () at test.cpp:14 14   { (gdb) n 15        Foo f; (gdb) 
>   16        f.i = 40; (gdb) call operator<<(std::cout, f)
>
> (gdb) set var f.i=5
>
> (gdb) call operator<<(std::cout, f)

and it printed `17` and `5`

Comment: May be it is fixed in the later gdb version. My gdb chokes on the return value of operator<< and does not flush its stdout buffer. When I call a dump() function of mine, gdb shows the results of the failed call to operatror<< as well.

Comment: I tried your example with gdb 7.10 and could not get it to work.  I compiled exactly like you did, set a break point on the last line of `main()` , called `operator<<' and got the same `incomplete type` error.  Could it be because I am using the older gcc 4.8.2?

Comment: May be, try also `-g3` instead of `-ggdb` if not help, then it is `gcc` fault

Comment: Do you get the error in addition to the output?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning `warning`, not `errror`, like this https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11171 but it print right value so I not care about its warnings

Comment: Hmm... I stand corrected. I also get the output followed by the warning. But it still does not work with my code. There is probably something about the type of my objects...

Comment: For me, the issue was that `std::cout` was line-buffering, and that the output was appearing in a different VSCode tab. Using `std::cerr` avoided the buffering issue.